# Where are the Rigid Body Tools in Blender 2.8

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I'm looking for the Rigid Body Tools that used to be accessible on the Tool Shelf in Blender up to 2.79. Since the removal of the shelf, I can't seem to find it in Blender 2.8 anymore. Here's the menu I'm looking for:

[image]

Where are these options hiding these days?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can access through the horizontal menu bar > *Object* > *Rigid Body*. I don't know if there's another way.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much - exactly what I was looking for!