# Set material density [kg/m³] instead of mass [kg]

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

Is there any way or plugin which allows enter material density in [kg/m³] instead of direct enter real mass [kg] how it is now in Blender. Blender knows the exact size of the object, so it is possible to calculate volume [m³] and then evaluate weight [kg] based on material density. I personally don't understand why there is just weight [kg] by default. With material density, there could be also possible to preselect common material like wood, steel, iron, plastic, glass, etc. It will allow us to make more realistic physics animation in a much shorter time. Do it now with many objects on the scenes is horrible.

Comment: *Blender knows the exact size of the object.* - Does it? Where can we see the exact size? What if the meshes have a hole (or are non manifold), do they even have a volume then?

Comment: Yes. Of course, there is also several CAD extension which helps with precise modeling. And of course, that is possible to create a mesh that has no volume, but you will not use such an object for rigid body simulation. There is 3D Print extension directly in blender which can evaluate volume and are of any selected object, of course also with holes or with applied modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, it is directly in blender itself.

Horizontal menu bar > Object > Rigid Body > Calculate Mass

As you can see here on the screenshot:

[image]
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/137448/99511

Bad thing is that you need to do it every time you change the side of the object. It is not updated automatically.